# pixi viewport drag bad working after select a child

Tags: javascript, webgl, mouseevent, pixi.js

[image]

When I drag on an empty stage, it moves fine.

But when I do this on my children, it gets annoying.

```
import { Application, Sprite, Texture } from 'pixijs';
import { Viewport } from 'pixi-viewport'

const app = new Application({
backgroundAlpha: 1,
width: innerWidth, height: innerHeight,
antialias: true,
})
document.body.appendChild(app.view)

const stage = new Viewport({
screenWidth: window.innerWidth,
screenHeight: window.innerHeight,
worldHeight: 1000,
worldWidth: 1000,
})
app.stage.addChild(stage)
stage.drag().pinch().wheel().decelerate().setZoom(0.5).clampZoom({ maxScale: 2, minScale: 0.3 }).interactiveChildren = true

for (let x = 0; x < 25; x++) {
for (let y = 0; y < 25; y++) {
Spawn(x, y)
}
}

function Spawn(x, y) {
const box = Sprite.from(Texture.WHITE)
box.position.set(x * Texture.WHITE.width, y * Texture.WHITE.height)
box.scale.set(0.90)
box.on('click', () => console.log('box clicked!'))
box.interactive = true
stage.addChild(box)
}
```

[Video of the problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Px0fwxF4DRGVugtgiirRamI2Y9wq5hVJ/view?usp=sharing)

I want to move on the boxes and click on them as well.

Comment: please also see : https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/discussions/8813

Comment: stage.hitArea = app.screen  - This was not the case either

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the propagation of `pointerdown` events on the boxes. As a result, the viewport dragging will never start since the viewport will not receive said event:

```js
box.on('pointerdown', (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[This](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.FederatedPointerEvent.html#stopPropagation) is the related documentation.

Comment: I tried this, but it still has the same behavior as before.

Comment: From my test, clicking on the boxes was preventing the drag but clicking on the small gaps between the boxes wasn't. Maybe is that what you're experiencing?

Comment: What browser are you using? Can you try with this pen? https://codepen.io/epaezrubio/pen/LYBdwdW

Comment: Google Chrome Version 109.0.5414.75 (Windows) (64-bit) - 
I have the same problem again

Comment: I'm using the same browser specs and the issue cannot be reproduced in the codepen. Are you using any kind of browser extension related to mouse events?